# Stop all docker containers at once on Windows

Tags: docker, command-line

How can I stop all docker containers running on Windows?

`docker stop` is for 1 container only.

Any command/script to make it stop all containers?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You could create a **batch-file** (*.bat* or *.cmd*) with these commands in it:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('docker ps -q') DO docker stop %%i
```

If you want to run this command directly in the console, replace `%%i` with `%i`, like:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker ps -q') DO docker stop %i
```

In **Git Bash** or **Bash for Windows** you can use this Linux command:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -q)
```

*Note: this will fail if there are no containers running*

For **PowerShell**, the command is very similar to the Linux one:

```
docker ps -q | % { docker stop $_ }
```

Answer (score 52):

For those who are interested this can be accomplished in Powershell using

```
docker ps -q | % { docker stop $_ }
```

Answer (score 11):

In PowerShell, you could also use this syntax

```
docker container stop $(docker container list -q)
```

Comment: Or `docker container stop $(docker ps -q)`

Comment: `docker container stop $(docker container ls --quiet) || true` if you need to ignore no containers error.

Answer (score 8):

If the motivation of the question is to recover the memory occupied by Docker (in my case, this was why I arrived at this page), I found that the only way was to stop Docker Desktop completely. You do that by right-clicking the **whale icon** in the notification area (bottom right) > **Quit Docker Desktop**.
When you restart Docker Desktop, all the containers reappear, and Docker even sets them to **up** again automatically.

Answer (score 3):

My two cents.

If you want to stop them filtered by some criteria

```
docker ps -a -q --filter "name=container_name" --format="{{.ID}}" | ForEach-Object -Process {docker stop $_ }
```

or if you want to stop and remove them all together

```
docker ps -a -q --filter "name=container_name" --format="{{.ID}}" | ForEach-Object -Process {docker rm $_ -f}
```

By using **pipe** and **foreach** I avoid the error returned when there are no containers of this kind on the specific machine because **docker stop** or **docker rm** require at least one argument.

This script is used with combination of

```
docker container run image_tag --name=container_name
```

in order to use the filter later on when you want to stop and remove the containers.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
```

to stop all running containers.

```
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```

to delete all containers.