# Docker unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -aq)

Tags: docker

I have multiple docker (version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4) containers running and I wish to stop them all at once. [This blog post](http://blog.baudson.de/blog/stop-and-remove-all-docker-containers-and-images) shows concisely exactly how to achieve this, great!

I can list all containers using `docker ps -aq` and have no issues.

However, when trying to stop all containers using the output of `docker ps -aq`, i.e. `docker stop $(docker ps -aq)`, I receive the following error:

> `unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -aq)`

**EDIT:** I'm running Windows 10 Version 10.0.17134.407 in a standard (elevated) command prompt.

Can anyone shed any insight into this?

Thanks.

Comment: which operating system and shell are you using?

Comment: @AlexandreJuma I've added that information to my question.

Comment: $() is a bash thing :)

Comment: @AlexandreJuma Uh of course, I forget when switching between systems so often!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can also run your command - `docker stop $(docker ps -aq)` in **PowerShell** or **Git Bash**; I would think the command fails because the `$(docker ps -aq)`  part of the command is Linux command and windows CMD does not know how to translate that.

Comment: this should be the accepted best answer!!

Comment: Best answer so far!

Answer (score 9):

In your Windows shell, you can do:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker ps -q') DO docker stop %i
```

Taken from other question: [Stop all docker containers at once on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48813286/stop-all-docker-containers-at-once-on-windows)