# Docker stop all containers

Tags: docker, docker-cleanup

I've seen many times the follwoing command to stop all docker containers:

**docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)**

There are two things that are not clear to me:

1. **docker ps -a** prints all containers, not only running ones, so what is the point to stop containers that are already stopped?
2. If **docker ps** returns/prints nothing (there are no running images) then **docker stop** blaims that it's not enough arguments.

What do I miss here? What is the best approach to cleanup an environment after docker?

Comment: The correct command is `docker stop $(docker ps -q)` - credits from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48813850/3665178

Answer (score 3):

use this will not run if the `docker ps` is empty:

```
docker ps -q | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker stop
```

normally you use `rm` and `system prune` if you really want to cleanup

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this oneliner:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq | tr '\n' ' ')
```