# unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -aq

Tags: docker

I follow tutorial https://phoenixnap.com/kb/remove-docker-images-containers-networks-volumes . My error

[image]

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1304]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\MyPC>docker container stop $(docker container ls -aq)
unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -aq)
See 'docker container stop --help'.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that `$`(passing output as args) not working in CMD.

Try to use `Git Bash` or `Bash for Windows` you can use this `Linux command`.

For cmd, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48813850/8207836).

Or, for Powershell:

`docker ps -q | % { docker stop $_ }`

Comment: It runs, https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/95699372-798aaf80-0c6e-11eb-9c84-624ae11c2592.png , then nothing deleted. Many things still running https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/95699434-99ba6e80-0c6e-11eb-9447-eab4f68014a2.png

Comment: This command worked correctly. But, it stoped containers only. Try use: `docker rm -f`
Another aspect, k8s will start new container to guarantee the availability of a specified number of identical Pods in a ReplicateSet

Comment: stop Kubernetes before delete.

Answer (score 0):

It is

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Reference document: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/